# php help hiding navigation with cookie

Tags: php, simplify

I have these tabs on my  navigation:

```
<li<?php if ($thisPage=="Customers") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
<li<?php if ($thisPage=="Trunks")  echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/trunks/">Trunks</a></li>
<li<?php if ($thisPage=="Settings")  echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></li>
```

and I only want to show them when admin is logged in:

```
if ($_COOKIE['custid'] == "admin") {

echo "Customers";
echo "Trunks";
echo "Settings";

}
```

How can I combine the two of these scripts???

Comment: Storing your admin flag in a cookie is probably the most unsafe thing you could ever do.

Comment: what is the best way to separate user content from admin content???

Comment: Use a session, and store your sessionid to admin on the server. NEVER trust the client... what if someone just edited the cookie to say they were an admin? Would that then give them control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE['custid'] == "admin") { ?>
<li<?php if ($thisPage=="Customers") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
<li<?php if ($thisPage=="Trunks")  echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/trunks/">Trunks</a></li>
<li<?php if ($thisPage=="Settings")  echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Pretty simple, put it inside the other one...

Answer (score 1):

Treating the "admin in cookie" issue as a separate issue...

```
<?php if($admin): ?>
    <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Customers"): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
    <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Trunks"): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><a href="/trunks/">Trunks</a></li>
    <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Settings"): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

PHP's inline syntax is much nicer  than using {} and echos inside html

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but:

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE['custid'] == "admin") { ?>
 <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Customers") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
 <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Trunks")  echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/trunks/">Trunks</a></li>
 <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Settings")  echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></li>
<?php } else { ?>
 <li><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
 <li><a href="/trunks/">Trunks</a></li>
 <li><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></li>
<?php } ?>

// OR

<li<?php if ($_COOKIE['custid'] == "admin" && $thisPage=="Customers") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
<li<?php if ($_COOKIE['custid'] == "admin" && $thisPage=="Trunks")  echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/trunks/">Trunks</a></li>
<li<?php if ($_COOKIE['custid'] == "admin" && $thisPage=="Settings")  echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></li>
```

And I agree with *@webdestroya* in the comments on the post itself; you should use a session or similar instead of a cookie to verify administrator status. I just didn't change it here for the sake of the example.